# Implementing Oauth2 with spring security in web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a web application in jsf , spring and hibernate. My current login is using spring security.  I also have an android app with the same functionality as the web application. Now I want to synchronize my android and web app to store the data on same DB. So I want to implement oauth2 and spring rest in my web application such that the android devices will need to authenticate first and get access to the method exposed. I try to merge oauth2 config in my spring security base on this tutorial [https://github.com/neel4software/SpringSecurityOAuth2](https://github.com/ksoumi/SpringSecurityOAuth2) , but am not able to get my access token through the url.  Any help on this? I want my login of the web application use only spring security. Whereas my login on android will use outh2 n spring security. Below is my spring n oauth2 config.. I would appreciate any help and I want to do my configuration in xml file. It's much easier to understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


<!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
    and what roles have access to them -->
<http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
    but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />


<!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
    and other things -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>


<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <security:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />



<!-- Spring security -->

<!-- <security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />
 -->


<security:http auto-config="false" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true" >
    <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
    <security:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureClass" authentication-success-handler-ref="successClass"
        login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="dashboard.xhtml" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" success-handler-ref="LogoutAction" />  
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </security:session-management>  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsf/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/run**" access="isAuthenticated()" />  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />    
</security:http>

<bean id="successClass" class="com.car.SuccessAction"/>

<bean id="failureClass" class="com.car.FailureAction" >
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/?login_error=true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" hash="sha"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.getMessageConverters(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:318)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
... 29 more
```

Pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>oro</groupId>
                <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>   <!-- Usata da Hibernate 4 per LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Stacktrace:

```
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceServerFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager] while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenServices' while setting bean property 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenServices' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStore' while setting bean property 'tokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore] for bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
... 26 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager] while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenServices' while setting bean property 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenServices' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStore' while setting bean property 'tokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore] for bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore
at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
... 40 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenServices' while setting bean property 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenServices' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStore' while setting bean property 'tokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore] for bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in class path resource [SIL-security-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore
at 
... 50 common frames omitted
      Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenServices' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStore' while setting bean property 'tokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore] for bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) 
... 56 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore] for bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at  ... 66 common frames omitted
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:236) ~[spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:392) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
... 72 common frames omitted

     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceServerFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
... 26 more
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2Authentication....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that you are getting is because of Jackson json converter. you need to add jackson-mapper-asl*.jar and jackson-core-asl*.jar as spring uses these jars to convert the response body in JSON format and also include spring-web*.jar in your project.

In your security xml replace

```
<bean id="tokenStore"
 class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />
```

with

```
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />
```

use

```
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"></property>
</bean>
```

Here is working security.xml. I have tested with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
        so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
        mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
    <http pattern="/test/*" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/test/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) -->
    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.DefaultUserApprovalHandler">
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="the_client"
            authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

        <oauth:client client-id="testclient"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
            secret="testsecret" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

</beans>
```

I have few dependencies of your code like... `SuccessAction` and `FailureAction`. I have tested this security configuration with latest oauth and spring-security-3.2.*

Comment: I have these two in my pom.xml:    
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>

Comment: do you have spring-web*.jar included in your pom.xml

Comment: I think the problem is on versioning. My spring security is using version 3.1 and spring 3.1.1 release. The example on github is using spring security 3.2 and spring 4.1 .  Is it really a problem? How to overcome this?

Comment: yes that is the reason... MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter came in 3.1.2

Comment: Normally my application is using spring 3.1.1 release and spring security 3.1.0 release. If I manage to upgrade my security to 3.2, will it works with spring security oauth2 ? Or i need to upgrade spring also to 4 ?

Comment: you need to upgrade spring to 3.1.2 or newer

Comment: See updated post with pom.xml. Am having the following exception.  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor
Any idea why?

Comment: I mange to update spring to 4 and security to 3.2.5. When I add security oauth 2.0.7, I get exception java.classnotfound. My application cannot find the oauth class even if the jar file is in my web project.

Comment: does your WEB-INF/lib contains oauth libraries? what classes it is not able to find?

Comment: Yes it is in the WEB-INF/lib. See updated post. I have post my stacktrace.

Comment: InMemoryTokenStore class is in "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store" package not in "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token"

Comment: Oh yeah the class is not in the package. How to include it?

Comment: Ok this one work. Now it's asking for this one : org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler
It's not in the package.

Comment: use org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.DefaultUserApprovalHandler instead

Comment: Ok I change it and I'm getting the following error :
 Invalid property 'tokenServices' of bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.DefaultUserApprovalHandler]: Bean property 'tokenServices' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: I have updated the answer see it... if not working will share you working xml config tommorow

Comment: Ok now am having this:
Error creating bean with name 'userApprovalHandler' defined in class path resource [CAR-security-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth2RequestFactory must be provided

Comment: Any other solution you can suggest? Thanks in Advance

Comment: OK  Now I don't have any error with this config file. Except I have to use my authentication manager since i have override some method for my login. My login is still working fine with my spring security. But I try to get a token using the following url:  http://localhost:8080/CAR_TEMPLATE/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=testclient&client_secret=testsecret&username=test&password=test  and I get http status 404. Any idea why?

Comment: Imran still here? I'm stuck with this.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are registering springSecurityFilterChain filter? Are you adding contextAttribute while registering filter

Comment: In my web.xml
<filter>
  <description>generated-spring-security-filter</description>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

Comment: add it like this : <filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher</param-value>
</init-param>

Comment: With this I can't even open my web apps. it throws this exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)
 com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)

Comment: What is the name spring root context.. Is it dispatcher-servlet.xml or something else?

Comment: It defines like this in my web.xml:

<servlet>
  <description>generated-servlet</description>
  <servlet-name>CAR Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:CAR-web-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

Comment: Can you plz name all your xml files?

Comment: See post below, I have post all my xml files

Comment: Imran, have you been able to find out where the problem is? I've already post all xml files

Comment: Imran , Do i need to add some configuration in web.xml in order to access the token url?Something like OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter?

Comment: Where are you adding your security xml configuration. I am not able to find any import statement in your configuration to include security configuration. I though your context name will be dispatcher-servlet.xml, thats why I asked to add <init-param> 
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name> 
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher‌​</param-value> 
    </init-param>. Please remove this from your web.xml

Comment: It is in applicationContext.xml. Sorry I forgot to post this one!

<import resource="classpath:CAR-security-context.xml"/>
 <import resource="classpath:CAR-service-context.xml"/>
 <import resource="classpath:CAR-dao-context.xml"/>

Comment: And where you are including applicationContext in your web.xml

Comment: No it's not. I don't know how it takes it. But my login works well with my spring security. Did I miss some config in my web.xml file?

Comment: Can you import everything in CAR-web-context.xml instead of importing it in applicationContext

Comment: Ok I will try this. According to you that thing should work ??

Comment: It's the same. http status 404. I've written a post where I explained how my login works. May be this can help you to understand why it's not working:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810123/issues-with-oauth2-configuration

Comment: I finally got a response from oauth with the token url. A popup appears saying: The server http://localhost:8080 requires a username and password. The servers says test/client.  Which username and password should I input?

Comment: You need to pass client id and client secret of the application.. you can find it in your security xml. I suggest you to use postman or any rest client and construct your url something like ../oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials and do a base64 encode of "<clientId>:<clientSecret>" add it in request as...  Authorization Basic header.

Comment: Do I have an authorization url? I need to include this in postman

Comment: OAuth2 provide 4 flows/grant types to get access token. If u are using directly token endpoint (in case of client_credentials and password) you don't need authorization url to generate access token. But if you want to use first two flows (authorization_code and implicit) you need authorization url (../oauth/authorize)

Comment: where is it? you need to include grant_type as query parameter.... /oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials

Comment: Use "http://localhost:8081/CAR_TEMPLATE/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials" url in your POSTMAN client and add Authorization header with value "Basic dGVzdGNsaWVudDp0ZXN0c2VjcmV0"

Comment: I'm getting this exception: HTTP Status 500 - /oauth/login.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource.  I don't have any folder called oauth!

Comment: Where did you get this value : "Basic dGVzdGNsaWVudDp0ZXN0c2VjcmV0 " ?

Comment: Ok manage to do it on postman: It says:" HTTP Status 404 - /CAR_TEMPLATE/oauth/token. The requested resource is not available."

Comment: I have done some research and found out that I should in include this in my web.xml: 
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CAR Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth/token</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

And now it says: "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported. Request method 'GET' not supported"

Any ideas how to proceed now?

Comment: I had to select POST I think and when I do it, I get this: "{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "Empty scope (either the client or the user is not allowed the requested scopes)"
}"

Comment: are you specifying scope parameter in query string?

Comment: I just add the scope parameter and now I get this : {
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Unsupported grant type: password"
}
In spring-config file, I have not specified scope for grant type:password.
<oauth:client client-id="testclient"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
            secret="testsecret" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"/>

Comment: use grant_type as client_credentials

Comment: I get this now :
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized grant type: client_credentials"
}

Comment: can you add client_credentials in <oauth:client authorized-grant-types="client_credentials,..." and then try

Comment: Ok I finally got the access token. But What should I change if I want to use grant_type = password? And why is it a POST request? Was it not supposed to be a GET method?

Comment: Ohh Great!!! finaly :)... to use password grant you need to specify that in <oauth:client authorized-grant-types="password,..." and you must have user's username and password whose protected resource you will be accessing. you need to pass username and password to token endpoint as query string or request body. token endpoint supports get request but it is better to use post and pass the username and password as request body.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The password grant type is already there and yet it said unsupported grant type. Currently I was using a hardcoded username and password. Now I want to revert back and used username and password from DB. How will I assign the role: Role_client to my users? Otherwise they won't be able to have access.

Comment: you should not assign role:ROLE_CLIENT to user, user will have its own ROLE_USER. To authenticate the user through DB just have a look at JdbcDaoImpl and DaoAuthenticationProvider class of spring security. If oauth is working please accept the answer

Comment: Accepted! My current login with spring security is using username and password from db. The config is in the file where we have oauth n spring security. You can have a look in my first post. I want to use the same username and password. To set up the db part is already there.

Comment: try to make post request to token endpoint with following parameter.. /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=<scope> and add authorization header as you are doing in case of client_credentials

Comment: My spring security is not working! When I log in my web application, it gives me my homepage. But when I click on a menu, it returns me on the login page. My spring security works well with version 3.1. Currently it is 3.2.5 . Spring security oauth 2.0.7 will not work with spring security 3.1?

Comment: I forgot to mention, Yes i can call username and password which is stored in DB from the token url. This one works.

Comment: Good.. So all is fine now?

Comment: No.. My login of my web application is not working. My login is supposed to authenticate only with spring security. It works great with spring security 3.1 but not with spring 3.2.5. Oauth2 does not works spring security 3.1!!!

Comment: Now what is the issue with login? any stacktrace

Comment: Nothing in the stacktrace..my login of my web application has stopped working since I upgrade to spring security 3.2.5. When I access my web app in browser, It gives me my login page as usual, as soon as I enter my username and password, it redirects me to my homepage which is good. But when I click on a menu or a button, it redirects me again on the login page (like it logs me out). If i revert my spring security to 3.1.0, it will work but the spring security oauth2 will stop working. I need to make login work with spring security 3.1! Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new question with complete scenario

Comment: I have already post a new question. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871190/upgrading-spring-security-from-3-1-0-to-3-2-5

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, You did not tell me Where did you get this value : "Basic dGVzdGNsaWVudDp0ZXN0c2VjcmV0 " ?

Comment: you need to take client_id and client secret of application and concatenate as client_id:client_secret and do a base64 encoding of it which will result in a encoded string ,add your authorization header with that value preceded by Basic

Comment: Oh ok I will need to pass this header when my android app authenticate with the web application?

Comment: I have observed something, If i removed username/password from my parameter, it still gives the access token. is it normal? It needs to authenticate first...?  http://localhost:8080/CAR_TEMPLATE/oauth/token?scope=read,write,trust&grant_type=client_credentials

Answer (score 0):

This is my Car-dao-context.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd        
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop         
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx      
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd        
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context      
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd        
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee      
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd         
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security      
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Scan for dao layer annotated beans -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.car" scoped-proxy="interfaces"/>

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Mark bean transactions as annotation driven -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- PropertyConfigurer for the DAO -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:CAR-dao.properties"/>

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Setup the transaction manager -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Using Atomikos Transaction Manager -->
<bean class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" destroy-method="close" id="atomikosTransactionManager" init-method="init">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="true"/>
    <property name="startupTransactionService" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="60"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" id="atomikosUserTransaction"/>

<!-- Configure the Spring framework to use JTA transactions from Atomikos -->
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
    <property name="transactionSynchronizationName" value="SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION"/>
</bean>

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Setup a data source -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="CARDS" jndi-name="jdbc/CAR_DB"
    cache="true" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="true"
    proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- Configure a JPA vendor adapter -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" id="CARJPAVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="${CAR.show_sql}"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${CAR.generateDdl}"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${CAR.dialect}"/>
            </bean>
<!-- EntityManager Factory that brings together the persistence unit, datasource, 
    and JPA Vendor -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="CAR">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="CARDS"/>
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="CAR"/>
                <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="CARJPAVendorAdapter"/>
                    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
                        <map>
                                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup"/>
                                    <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="on_close"/>
                        </map>
                    </property>
            </bean>
```

This is my Car-service-context.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd   
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd   
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd      
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd      
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd   
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang   
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd">

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Scan for service layer annotated beans -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.car" scoped-proxy="interfaces"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

This is my Car-web-context.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Spring 3.0 configuration -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Mark bean transactions as annotation driven -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Register Multi Part Resolve -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->   
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.skyway.spring.util.web.binary.ModelBindingMultipartResolver" />

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Register Streamed Binary Content View -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->   
<bean id="streamedBinaryContentView" class="org.skyway.spring.util.web.binary.ModelAttributeStreamer" />

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Bean Name View Resolver used to Redirect to Beans by id, required by Binary Content View -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<bean id="beanNameViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
</bean>


<bean id="webInfViewResolver" class="org.skyway.spring.util.viewresolution.AbsolutePathViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="order" value="-1" />
</bean>
```

And finally my web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">


 <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
 </context-param>

<servlet>
    <description>generated-servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>CAR Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:CAR-web-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<filter>
    <description>
        generated-spring-security-session-integration-filter
    </description>
    <filter-name>SpringSecuritySessionIntegrationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <description>generated-persistence-filter</description>
    <filter-name>CARFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>CAR</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <description>generated-sitemesh-filter</description>
    <filter-name>Sitemesh Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter> 
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name> 
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher‌​</param-value> 
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringSecuritySessionIntegrationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HRBFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Sitemesh Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/CAR</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>CAR</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-unit-ref>

  <persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/CAR</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>CAR</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```