# Spring Security 3.2.5 does not authenticate user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a web application with login using spring security 3.1.0 which is working fine. Now I have a mobile version of my web application. As such I want to used the oauth2 to login on my android app. I had to implement spring security oauth2 2.0.7 in my web application. In order for this to work, I had to upgrade my spring security to 3.2.5. My oauth2 authentication is working great with spring 4 and spring security 3.2.5. However my login of my web application has stopped working since I upgrade to spring security 3.2.5. When I access my web app in browser, It gives me my login page as usual, as soon as I enter my username and password, it redirects me to my homepage which is good. But when I click on a menu or a button, it redirects me again on the login page (like it logs me out). If i revert my spring security to 3.1.0, it will work but the spring security oauth2 will stop working. In order for both to work I have to keep my spring security on 3.2.5 . Below is my spring-security.xml and web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
    so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
    mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/test/*" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/test/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>


<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.DefaultUserApprovalHandler">
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="the_client"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="testclient"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="testsecret" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

<!-- Spring security -->



<security:http auto-config="false" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true" >
    <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
    <security:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailed" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccess"
        login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/dashboard.xhtml" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" success-handler-ref="logoutAction" />  
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </security:session-management>  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsf/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/run**" access="isAuthenticated()" />  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />    
</security:http>

<bean id="success" class="com.car.loginSuccess"/>

<bean id="failure" class="com.car.loginFailed" >
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/?login_error=true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />

 <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" hash="sha"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager> 



</beans>
```

web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">


 <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
 </context-param>

<servlet>
    <description>generated-servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>CAR Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:CAR-web-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<filter>
    <description>
        generated-spring-security-session-integration-filter
    </description>
    <filter-name>SpringSecuritySessionIntegrationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <description>generated-persistence-filter</description>
    <filter-name>CARFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>CAR</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <description>generated-sitemesh-filter</description>
    <filter-name>Sitemesh Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter> 
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name> 
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher‌​</param-value> 
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringSecuritySessionIntegrationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HRBFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Sitemesh Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/CAR</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>CAR</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-unit-ref>

  <persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/CAR</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>CAR</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

Pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>oro</groupId>
                <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>   <!-- Usata da Hibernate 4 per LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Class LoginSuccess.java

```
public class LoginSuccess implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
@Autowired
private LeaveUsersService leaveUsersService;

@Autowired
private UsersComponent usersComponent;



public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) 
{       
    UsersComponent user = usersService.getUserById(authentication.getName());

    try
    {
        if{
            //some codes here to check if account has expired.

        }
        else{
            request.getSession().setAttribute("lastLogin", user.getLastLoginDate());
            user.setLastLoginDate(Calendar.getInstance()));             
            usersService.saveUsers(user);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(user.getUserName()+"count", null);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/dashboard.xhtml");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        log.error("Exception "+user +e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

}
```

Class LoginFailed.java

```
public class LoginFailed extends ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler {
@Autowired
private UsersService usersService;


@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);

    String userName = request.getParameter("j_username");


    if(request.getSession().getAttribute(userName+"count")!=null)
    {
        String attr = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(userName+"count");


        int count = Integer.parseInt((attr.split("@"))[1]);
        if(count > 2)
        {
            Users user = usersService.getUserById(userName);
            if(user!=null)
            {
                user.setAccountBlocked("1");
                usersService.saveUsers(user);
                count = 0; //reset the count to allow the user to change his password
            }

        }
        count++;
        request.getSession().setAttribute(userName+"count", userName+"@"+count);            
    }
    else
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(userName+"count", userName+"@1"); 

    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you increase maximum-sessions more than one. may be five and test

Comment: Still the same. Whatever I click on the homepage, it redirects me on the login page (login-page="/login.xhtml")

Comment: Do I need to implement some classes for oauth2 to validate user ?

Comment: I found that as soon as I login on the web app and click on anything it returns me this url which is defined in my spring security file: login-page="/login.xhtml" Instead it should have called the class loginSuccess and returns this page: default-target-url="/dashboard.xhtml" />
I try to change this page="/login.xhtml" to page="/loginxxxx.xhtml"(something which does not exists), It returns me to this url /loginxxxx.xhtml
Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @Imran Do you have a solution for this? I have put a breakpoint in my class LoginSuccess, it do enters the authentication method but I can't understand why it returns back to the login page! With spring security 3.1 it works well.

Comment: @Imran any help pls? I'm stuck with this..